# Construct dataframe from pairwise Word Mover Distance score list

Tags: python, matrix, nlp, word-embedding

I'd like to run PCA analysis on a list of pairwise sentence distance (word mover distance) I had.  So far I've gotten a similarity score on each pair of sentences. Stored all the pairwise similarity scores in a list. My main question is:

How to construct a matrix that contains these similarity score with the original sentences' index? Currently, the list only contains each pair's score. Haven't found a way to map the scores back to the sentence itself yet.

My ideal dataframe looks like this:

```
>             Sentence1  Sentence2  Sentence3   
 Sentence1.     1          0.5        0.8
 Sentence2      0.5        1          0.4
 Sentence3      0.8        0.4        1
```

However, the similarity score list I have looks like this, without index:

> [0.5, 0.8, 0.4]

How do I transform it to a dataframe that I can run PCA on? Thanks!

----steps I took to construct the pairwise similarity score

```
# Tokenize all sentences in a column
tokenized_sentences = [s.split() for s in df[col]]

# calculate distance between 2 responses using wmd
def find_similar_docs(sentence_1, sentence_2):
   distance = model.wv.wmdistance(sentence_1, sentence_2)
   return distance

# find response pairs
pairs_sentences = list(combinations(tokenized_sentences, 2))

# get all similiarity scores between sentences
list_of_sim = []
for sent_pair in pairs_sentences:
   sim_curr_pair = find_similar_docs(sent_pair[0], sent_pair[1])
   list_of_sim.append(sim_curr_pair)
```

It would be a lot easier if I have "1" instead of tokenized sentence (["I", "open", "communication", "culture"]) as index. :) So I'm a bit stuck here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a distance matrix with numpy, then convert to a pandas dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# calculate distance between 2 responses using wmd
def find_similar_docs(sentence_1, sentence_2):
    distance = model.wv.wmdistance(sentence_1, sentence_2)
    return distance
  
# create distance matrix
tokenized_sentences = [s.split() for s in df[col]]
l = len(tokenized_sentences)
distances = np.zeros((l, l))
for i in range(l):
    for j in range(l):
        distances[i, j] = find_similar_docs(tokenized_sentences[i], tokenized_sentences[j])

# make pandas dataframe
labels = ['sentence' + str(i + 1) for i in range(l)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=distances, index=labels, columns=labels)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to use the original index associated with these scores. For example, it could be sentence_2 and sentence_4 are associated with 0.5. Is there a way for me to retrieve that information and use it as labels?

Comment: I would need to know how the similarity score list was created to get the original labels/index.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Just updated my original post.

Comment: thanks! After 3 hours, it worked! Quick follow up question, the column names are "sentence 1", "sentence 2". Do you know if there is a way for me to trace back to which sentence does sentence 1 refer to in the original dataframe? Thanks again!

Comment: `Sentence1` would be equivalent to `tokenized_sentences[0]`